# Entity Framework Context.Set<T> throwing error "Entity type 'ClassName' is not part of the model for the current context"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 2 classes that represents the same table in the Database, Difference is in the properties of these classes. I am using this way because of differences in the custom fields in databases the application will connect to.

```
 [Table("T1")]
    public class Class1
    {
      .
      .
    }



 [Table("T1")]
        public class Class2
        {
          .
          .
        }
```

Here Now i am using the set method to get data. I have not declared anything in the DB context.

```
DbSet<Class1> set = context.Set<Class1>();
return set.Where(p => p.Active == "Y");
```

But system throws error

> 'Entity type 'Class1' is not part of the model for the current context'

What i am trying to achieve is to define the model for the DbSet dynamically, is this possible in some other way?

Comment: Do you have a DbSet in your context of type `DbSet<Class1>`?

Comment: I have to include that even if i have the table attribute?
So how should i dynamically change the class to use? like in some cases i have to use class1, other cases use class2.

Comment: You always need a matching `DbSet` in your context. How could it possibly change between two classes, that makes no sense? Your database doesn't suddenly change does it?

Comment: so the same application will be used with two databases having similar structure, but because of the custom fields in table, the table structure is different in both. So my understanding was i can use two classes n use based on the requirement during runtime. By the way why we even need the 'Set' when we declare the DBSet in context?

Comment: The `Table` attribute in this case is only setting the name of the table to use, the context still needs to have a `DbSet<Class1>` etc, registered. Based on your previous comment are you sure it wouldn't be better to have two separate contexts, one for each database? And use whichever context is relevant at runtime, as opposed to one context that can work with either database.

Comment: So you just have a single table that changes depending on which system you connect to?

Comment: yea, currently only this table that is used by the application have difference. All base columns are same in both databases, but there are custom columns which is different. One instance of the application will connect to any one DB only.

Answer (score 0):

To use the [`DbContext.Set<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-3.1) method, your context needs to have a matching [`DbSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-3.1) property. If you have a setup where one of the tables changes, then you have a couple of options.

1. Add both `DbSet<Class1>` and `DbSet<Class2>` properties to your `DbContext`:

   ```
   public DbSet<Class1> Class1s { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Class2> Class2s { get; set; }
   ```

   I'm personally **not** a fan of doing this.
2. Have a generic context and make the table that changes inherit from a common base. For example:

   ```
   public class BaseClass
   {
       //shared properties go in here
   }

   public class Class1 : BaseClass
   {
       //custom properties here
   }

   public class Class2 : BaseClass
   {
       //custom properties here
   }
   ```

   And your context could look like this:

   ```
   public class MyContext<T> : DbContext
       where T : BaseClass
   {
       public DbSet<T> Class1s { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Second one makes better sense. Is there any other way to define the model for the DbSet dynamically?

Comment: I suppose you could look at adding configuration manually in the modelbuilder, but that sound horrible and fraught with issues to me.

Comment: second method gives me error "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'." Also not able to use Interface to define DBset

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong there. Can't help more as I don't know your code.

Comment: From my search, I dont thik you can just derive classes and use. Have you tried this work?

Comment: In almost every one of my EF projects I have a base class for all entities.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: Yes, but the code you show above doesn't have any of that. Have you made sure that you are using the generic type as the `DbSet` and **not** your base class?

Comment: without discriminator column in DB, this will work? anyway i have changed it to read using procedure to my objects.

Comment: You only need a discriminator column if you are storing multiple types in the same table. That would mean you have a `DbSet<BaseFoo>` and derived classes from `BaseFoo`.